# Validating Input values through Java Regex . I have a requirement to acccept values from 0.01 to 1

Tags: java, regex

I'm struggling with a regex problem. The requirement is, I need to take all values from 0.01 to 1 . 
Am using a regex ^[0]+(\0-9]{1,10})?$|^[1]  . This excepts values from 0 to 1 . But the requirements is to accept values ranging from 0.01 to 1 except 0.0 and 0.00.  Am not sure how to have a regex for this I don have access to java code to validate the input . It should be controlled only through Regex .
Need Help on this

Comment: I don't understand, is this a Java question or not?

Comment: You can test your Java code using [ide one](http://ideone.com/)

Comment: I guess you need to add `\\.` in your regex to validate the usage of the dot.

Comment: @Marcelo : This i need it in a Tool which accepts only regex and validates the input provided. Am not quite sure about regex validations hence had to post on this. The tools works on Java though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this regex seems to be what you want

"0\.[1-9]?|0\.[0-9][1-9]|1"